# Create .zshrc file for aliases

Tags: macos, alias, zshrc

i am trying to create permanent alias on my mac terminal. The file .zshrc is not present so i need to create it myself.

I have create the file and added the following alias as test

alias ll='ls -la'

But when i run the command ll it is recognized. anyone could help what i am doing wrong ?
when i create the alias directly from the command line it worked and the terminal restart the alias is lost. so i am looking for a permanent solution

thanks for helping how to add properly the alias in zshrc file

Hey guys,

i am trying to create permanent alias on my mac terminal. The file .zshrc is not present so i need to create it myself.

I have create the file and added the following alias as test

alias ll='ls -la'

But when i run the command ll it is recognized. anyone could help what i am doing wrong ?
when i create the alias directly from the command line it worked and the terminal restart the alias is lost. so i am looking for a permanent solution

thanks for helping how to add properly the alias in zshrc file

Answer (score 0):

After a `.zshrc` file is created, you need to run a command so changes can take effect: `source .zshrc`.

This is for the current active zsh window. It's the same if you close the current window and open a new one.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it worked after the source .zshrc